# Struggling with Pandas to JSON in Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe which is created in a django view:

```
Date        Actual ticks
26-Sep-14   20
29-Sep-14   40
15-Oct-14   -10
20-Oct-14   5
```

The data is read in from a csv file using pandas, then changed into a json object, and then sent to a django template:

```
df = pd.read_csv('article/DailyStats.csv', usecols=['Date', 'Actual ticks'])
df.to_json()
return render_to_response('article/test.html', {'df': df})
```

Now is where I am having a problem, when I try to use the JSON object in the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON({{ df }}, function(data){
        //do something
    })
 </script>
```

In my Chrome browser console I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

If I look at Sources in the browser, I see the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON(           Actual ticks
        Date                   
        26-Sep-14            20
        29-Sep-14            40
        15-Oct-14            -10
        20-Oct-14            5, function(data){
        })
    </script>
```

All I want is a JSON with a list of keys (ie: dates), and values (ie: 'Actual ticks'). Im guessing it has something to do with the column headings messing something up.

Ultimately I want to be able to loop through the json to display the dates and corresponding values, but I cant do that until this error is no longer happening.

Many thanks for any advice.

UPDATE: Thanks to @Anzel who pointed out I was not assigning the JSON object to a variable. I have now done that ie:
    df_json = df.to_json()

but the resulting json is not valid:

```
[
    [
        &quot;26-Sep-14&quot;,
        20
    ],
    [
        &quot;29-Sep-14&quot;,
        40
    ],
    [
        &quot;15-Oct-14&quot;,
        -10
    ],
    [
        &quot;20-Oct-14&quot;,
        5
    ]
]
```

Any idea how to get it to create a valid JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, you're not passing the **json** object to the `render_to_response`, you only pass `df` as a **DataFrame**.

```
# this line, you're calling to_json, but haven't assigned to df itself
df.to_json()

# assign it to df_json (or df if you want), and pass it again to render_to_response
df_json = df.to_json()
return render_to_response('article/test.html', {'df': df_json})
```

And in your template, since you've already passed the **json** object, you don't need to do any ajax call, just parse the json will be fine, something like this (haven't tested yet, but should work as expected), now **updated** with `|safe` and wrapped with quotes as pointed by @RemcoGerlich:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json_data = JSON.parse("{{ df_json|safe }}"); // df if you assign df as the json
    // do whatever you want with json_data as usual
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Anzel. Silly mistake of mine. I have made the change. However the resulting json is not valid. I have updated the original  question to show what the json looks like.

Comment: @darkpool, I've updated my answer to cover the part in javaScript you need to change too.

Comment: thank you for your help. The JSON string is now valid. I had to use {{df_json | safe}} but never the less it is valid now. I checked it with JSONLint. But for some reason it is now giving an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: @darkpool, do you want Date as one of your keys? remember `DataFrame.to_json` will convert **{column -> {index -> value}}**, you probably forgot to `set_index`.

Comment: With your help and the suggestion from @RemcoGerlich it is now working. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

As for your second problem, Django is escaping the string so that it is safe to use in HTML (can't include extra bits of HTML or JavaScript).

To tell Django not to do that, use the `safe` template filter.

Also, as this needs to become a string literal in JavaScript, you want to put quotes around it:

```
var json_data = JSON.parse("{{ df_json|safe }}");
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Thanks to @Anzel and yourself it is finally working.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, great call with that `|safe`